# How do my iFrame in 2 or 3 columns?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The code below is ugly, can you help me put it into columns please? 
2 or 3 so i can view the frames on full screen.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<br><br>
<p><input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://goole.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="two" id="two" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="one.location.href='http://bing.com/';document.getElementById('one').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="one.location.href='http://zazzle.com/';document.getElementById('one').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="one" id="one" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="three.location.href='bing.com/';document.getElementById('three').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="three.location.href='http://jeeves.com/';document.getElementById('three').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="three" id="three" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

<p><input type="button" onclick="four.location.href='bing.com/';document.getElementById('four').frameBorder=1" value="T">
<input type="button" onclick="four.location.href='http://jeeves.com/';document.getElementById('four').frameBorder=1" value="U">
<br><iframe src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3506/screenshots/937913/gameover.png" name="four" id="four" marginwidth="10" marginheight="" width="300" height="300"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"> </iframe></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for 3 columns

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://goole.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://goole.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://goole.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="T" />
        <input type="button" onclick="two.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';document.getElementById('two').frameBorder=1" value="U" />
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
}

.embed-responsive-16by9::before {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-4 {
        max-width: 33.33333%;
        flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JankiGanhi Looks amazing thanks however my buttons are not working. The original code was for web forms. Not multi media, but when i click the button it should bring up another form. The first this inside the iframe box i want is a image.  Then once the user click a button it should bring up the form that fits perfect inside the iframe. The css is awesome, but for some reason the button are not working not. please advise

Comment: please help my buttons are not working. The original code was for web forms. Not multi media, but when i click the button it should bring up another form. The first this inside the iframe box i want is a image. Then once the user click a button it should bring up the form that fits perfect inside the iframe. The css is awesome, but for some reason the button are not working not. please advise

Comment: Actually I am not understand exactly what you want. You can ask the other question related this issue.

Comment: I have emails forms written in PHP . My team all have their own email addresses. INSTEAD of creating each team members a web page for their email contact form, i did iFrames with  buttons that redirect to each form that contacts that team member. So the i frames has to show the form not media. I like how the iframes are on the whole page but the button to access a different webpage does not work. how do i fix this?

Comment: Sorry @Varoon Ramtahal I have no idea about this issue. You can ask the other question on stackoverflow  related this issue because in this question you want to  design for iframe which is done but now your problem is other so you can ask other question regarding onclick buttons are not working or exactly you want.

Comment: Good Point. I'll ask another question. Thanks you for all your help. it looks awesome.